# Solidity: Function with same name but different parameter possible?

Tags: solidity, compilation

Will the contract auto detect wether I am calling the function with or without parameter?

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract A{
    function test() public{
        //do something
    }

    function test(uint256 param) public{
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the way the contract knows what function you're calling is that it uses a _function selector_. The function selector is the first four bytes of every transaction you send to a contract, and those are the first four bytes of the keccak256 hash of the function signature. So because `keccak256("test()")` is different from `keccak256("test(uint256)")`, they're completely different functions with no ambiguity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, function overloading is possible, see here:

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#function-overloading

Example from the docs:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract A {
    function f(uint _in) public pure returns (uint out) {
        out = 1;
    }

    function f(uint _in, bytes32 _key) public pure returns (uint out) {
        out = 2;
    }
}
```